# It asks to give the values but instead of giving an answer. It is giving me None

Tags: python-3.x

Here I created a module.

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = input("Enter your name: ")
        self.account_number = int(input("Enter your account number: "))
    def withdraw(self):   # it receives values from for
        if withdraw1 > current_balance:
            print ("You have entered a wrong number: ")
        else:
            print ("The current balance is: ", current_balance - withdraw1)
```

---

```
import TASK2 # I am importing the module I created 

c = TASK2.Employee()
def for(self):
    c.withdraw1 = int(input("enter number: "))
    c.current_balance = int(input("Enter the current balance: "))
d = method(c.withdraw) # here I am trying to pass the values to withdraw
print (d)
```

The problem I get is that although it asks for the values instead of giving me an answer it gives me None.

Comment: First thing, it does not ask for values.

Comment: Where is `method` defined?

Comment: Why not use "#" for comments?

Comment: I did use '#' at first, but in suggestions they said I should use '>'

Comment: ">" only outside codeblocks. Also where does it asks for values? What is "it"?

Comment: @mypetlion sorry I forgot to change it to for.

Comment: Right now, I see two issues. (1, minor) Your `for` function isn't using it's `self` parameter, making it redundant. (2, major issue) You should call the `withdraw` method by `c.withdraw()`, not `c.withdraw`.

Comment: I added the parenthesis (don't know how I forgot about that), now it's giving me the error withdraw1 is not defined.

Comment: Also it was required in the task that I am doing to make the for function.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding functions and return statements. I suggest digging up a tutorial to understand them better before having another go at the task. See my answer for other issues with the code.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my take on your code.

```
# TASK2.py
class Employee:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = input("Enter your name: ")
        self.account_number = int(input("Enter your account number: "))

        # make sure you initialise your member variables!
        self.withdraw_val = 0            # withdraw1 is ambiguous, so I use withdraw_val instead
        self.current_balance = 0

    # receives values from for ### no it doesn't, right now, it GIVES values TO your "for" function
    def withdraw(self):   
        if self.withdraw_val > self.current_balance:   # remember to use "self." to
                                                       # access members within the class
            print ("You have entered a wrong number: ")
        else:
            # again, remember "self."
            print ("The current balance is: ", self.current_balance - self.withdraw_val)
```

---

```
# TASK2sub.py

import TASK2

c = TASK2.Employee()

def for_employee(employee): # (1) don't use "self" outside a class
                            # it's contextually unconventional
                            # (2) "for" is a keyword in Python, don't use it for naming
                            # variables/functions, it'll mess things up

    employee.withdraw_val = int(input("Enter value to withdraw: "))
    employee.current_balance = int(input("Enter the current balance: "))

    return employee.withdraw_val  # not entirely sure what you want to return
                              # but you should definitely return something
                              # if you're going to assign it to some variable


d = for_employee(c.withdraw()) # "for_employee" function needs a return statement
                               # ".withdraw()" method should also require a return statement
print(d)
```

Note: I'll be referring to your original `for` function as `for_employee` from now on. Also note that I'm still hazy about what you're trying to accomplish and that there is most probably a more suitable name for it.

Since your original `for_employee` function didn't return anything, it returns `None` by default. (This explains the output you saw.)

---

I think you're misunderstanding how functions work in general. For example,

```
d = for_employee(c.withdraw())
print(d)
```

Your comment for the `.withdraw()` method is inaccurate.

> "it receives values from for"

More accurately, `c.withdraw()` will first be computed, then whatever it returns is passed into the `for_employee` function as a parameter. Instead of "receiving values from", the `withdraw` method "gives values to" the `for_employee` function.

Something more reasonable would be

```
c.withdraw()         # on a line by itself, since it doesn't return anything
d = for_employee(c)  # pass the entire object, since you'll be using self.withdraw_val and whatnot

print(d)
```

---

Another issue is with conventional naming. This is what I get from the IDLE (with Python 3.7) when defining a function named `for`

```
>>> def for(a): return a
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Again, *`for`* is a keyword in Python, **don't** use it for naming your variables, functions, or classes.

With `self`, it's less severe (but I could see that it's confusing you). `self` is more of a convention used in class methods. But `for_employee` *isn't* a class method. So conventionally speaking, the parameter shouldn't be named `self`.

(I find the code spaghetti-ish, it might benefit if you refactor the code by moving the `for_employee` method into the class itself. *Then* it would completely make sense to use `self`.)

Comment: Not behind my computer now, but can you add a line using *the keyword `for`* somewhere at the end? Just to check if using that as a function name does not mess things up for Python.

Comment: You're right, I'm getting `invalid syntax` for `def for()`.

Comment: I had to do a little editing but the code finally started working. Thank you.